# mongodb best array match

Tags: mongodb, find

Suppose I have the following structure

```
[{    
    name: 'John',    
    tags: ['unix','databases']    
},    
{    
    name: 'Jane',    
    tags: ['excel', 'power-point','word', 'outlook']   
},   
{  
    name: 'Smith',  
    tags: ['databases', 'linux', 'android']  
}]
```

and I want to search for people with `['databases','servers','c++']`

I want a query which will give me that the two best matches are Smith and John with one match each.

This feels similar to having two term vectors and finding cosine product   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model

P.S.
I realize I can probably do a $in and then calculate number of similar terms in my program(written in Java), but is there a way to get the answer from mongo itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think why do not you use the map-reduce. Create the Inverted index of your tags in the new collection and store the ID against the Tags . then you can count the matches of all the tags and then display sorted by maximum matches . Check one of blog here : http://ngsiolei.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-inverted-index-in-mongodb.html . Even though it looks like more text search but you can also use the same. Even in future this approach will give you flexibility to add some weight-age to your tags to get better result . The collection will look like this. So when I search for C++ for Database both ,  i will get James in both and I will sum it 2 and J will get 1 , So James is matching more. In this way we will create one document for each tag and it will be the Id , so your search will be faster. If you want some easy way use the Aggregation Framework (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) and use the unwind on the tags column

```
         C++ : ["James" , "J" ] , Database : ["James"]
```

Comment: tell me if i got this right.
I make a collection with as: tag: "<tag>" names:[<array of names>] and then I get names for all the tags I want and then find best match?

Comment: Updated my answer , please have a look

Comment: Got it, but my problem is the later processing. Once I have the array of all names, I need to programatically calculate most number of occurrences right? A relatively common tag example: "Windows" will return thousands of names

Comment: I have add one more option now , aggregate framework just see if it is right approach way